# Why I cannot read my custom header in scala view?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In my Play 2 app, in a method from controller I add a new header like:

```
def index(id: Option[Long]) = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
....
Ok(views.html.platform.alerts.index(request.user, currentUserAlerts, 
   TweetsDAO.loadTweets(alertId, None, 15)))
        .withHeaders("isAdmin" -> userSettings.get.isAdmin.toString)
}
```

and I want to access the header in alerts.index scala view like:

```
@request.headers.get("isAdmin")
```

where request is defined as implicit in my view:

```
(implicit request: RequestHeader)
```

but nothing is shown.

If I print all headers in scala view, isAdmin is not there.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `isAdmin` is a very strange name for an HTTP header. Are you sure this isn't actually a method defined on whatever `request.user` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ok.withHeaders(...)` adds headers to the `Result` returned to the user, not the `RequestHeader`, and is thus not passed to the view.

I don't see the point in trying to modify the `RequestHeader` when trying to pass some flag such as `isAdmin` to the view. Why not just add an explicit `isAdmin: Boolean` parameter to the view and pass it? That way you'd have to explicitly determine whether the user is an administrator, rather than relying on a header being added to the request, which can easily be overlooked.